# JavaScript. Cannot iterate an object with Object.keys () to get new

Tags: javascript, iterator

I have an object at the input, how do I return the modified object on the basis of the existing one?

I used `Object.keys()` for this purpose in conjunction with the iterator `map()`. But something does not work, I get undefined.

```js
let objjjj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}

console.log(
  Object.keys(objjjj).map((key, i) => {
    key: objjjj[key] + 1
  })
)
```

Comment: Arrow functions returning an object must have said object in brackets, to distinguish from a code block. Also note the result your current code will be producing, with said brackets, is very peculiar. Most interesting is that you do not use computed property names, aka all objects will have a property called `key`. Last but least, you log an array of objects (one for each property), which doesn't sound like what you want at all.

Comment: `Object.keys(objjjj).forEach(key => objjjj[key]++);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some parenthesis to wrap curly brackets in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Otherwise it is treated as block statement, where the standard return of `undefined` takes place.

For creating a single object, you could spread the single objects to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
let object = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 };
    
console.log(
    Object.assign(...Object.keys(object).map((key, i) => ({ [key]: object[key] + 1 })))
);
```

While you need key and value, you could take [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
let object = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 };
    
console.log(
    Object.assign(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v + 1 })))
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the new obj as it was, istead of creaing an extra objects inside. I mean `const obj = { 'key': 3, "key": 4 ....}`

Comment: it does not work with same keys. please add a possible alternative result.

Comment: I do not need the same keys. Just like in the question example above

Comment: and which key names do you want?

Comment: @MaxTravis you mean you need an object with the same keys but different values?

Comment: I need to have on outpute some like `let objjjj = {
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
  c: 5
}`

Comment: @NinaScholz isn't just easier and more readable to use `reduce`?

Comment: @J.Pichardo, it's just a new approach.

Comment: @NinaScholz can't argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

When you return an object from an arrow function is necessary that you surround it with parentheses:

```js
let obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: obj[key] + 1
  }), {})
)

// Or by using Object.entries


console.log(
  Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: value + 1
  }), {})
)
```

#### UPDATE:

Based on the comment from the other answer you could use `reduce` and the spread operator to fully map an object into another object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value instead to assign again to key.

```js
let objjjj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}

console.log(
  Object.keys(objjjj).map((key, i) => {
    return objjjj[key] + 1
  })
)
```